# Yii2 GridView widget, need to reverse on-click sort order

Tags: php, sorting, gridview, yii2, dataprovider

I need help with Yii2 GridView widget.
Issue is:
If you click on unsorted column name it will sort, by default from min to max(like SORT_ASC const in defaultOrder). What should i change to reverse sort order on click, it should be from max to min(like SORT_DESC).

There is no problem to choose default sort order onload, i need change it's onclick order. Sort options of dataProvider are:

```
            'sort' => [
            'attributes' => ['weekly_length','name', 'market','unique','sessions','retentions', 'session_length_summary',],
            'defaultOrder' => ['weekly_length' => SORT_DESC],
          ],
```

Comment: if you click again it will sort it DESC and if clicked again then ASC.

Comment: Ther is a big table, and it could take a long time to sort twice. I try to save user's time/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Reverse Your Sort Order as : -

```
'sort' => [
            'attributes' => [
                'weekly_length' => [
                    'asc' => ['weekly_length' => SORT_DESC,],
                    'desc' => ['weekly_length' => SORT_ASC],
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

Comment: Good idea, but not perfect. Works coorectly, but arrow, that showing sort order is reversed)
Anyway thanks. I'll wait for a couple hours, if no better solution will suggested  - take yours.

Comment: Use your idea. Thanks again/

Answer (score 1):

You can use as below:

```
$dataProvider->setSort([
             'attributes' => [
                     'weekly_length' => [
                        'asc' => ['weekly_length' => SORT_DESC],
                         'desc' => ['weekly_length' => SORT_ASC],

                     'defaultOrder' => ['weekly_length' => SORT_DESC]
                ],
            ]
      ]);
```

Comment: This is almost the same as first answer, but allow you change it without searching declaration of datProvider. Minus - it rewrites existed sort preferences, so be careful.